# My ANSYS model meshing is showing problem where I don't see my model and small blue rectangle appears. Is there any way to solve this?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, modeling, ansys, ansys-workbench, meshing

I'm new to ANSYS and just started using it. I encountered a problem when I click the model option; ANSYS Mechanical opens, but there is this blue rectangle, which is supposed to be big and show my model, but it appears as in the photo, and sometimes just a small part of my model is visible. Is there any way to solve this? My version is 2023 R2.

[image]

Comment: look for "reset layout" of "reset workspace"